# Share node modules between multiple ionic projects

Tags: node.js, ionic2

Each time a new ionic project is created, the ionic CLI downloads the respective templates followed by respective node modules.

In case of more than one ionic project, each project individually download the node modules.

Is it possible to share these node modules among multiple projects to optimize the data download, storage space and data replication ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at following documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders

In short words, if node.js doesn't found package in ./node_modules of your project, it tries to find package in other paths, described in NODE_PATH:

1: $HOME/.node_modules

2: $HOME/.node_libraries

3: $PREFIX/lib/node